# Gradient of $R(t')$

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields

It's from book 2 of L&L.

[image]

I tried to wrap my head around it about how grad $R(t')$ would be transformed into a function of grad *t*' and the unit function in the direction of R in the last equation; it's just not too straightforward for me.
I know the result is true because taking simple steps do lead into the same conclusions, as is explained in another post below, but how does the book proceed in such a straightforward manner I am very confused.
[link for gradient of retarded time](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/486263/4-gradient-of-retarded-time)

Comment: I think (63.1) is probably relevant, but you didn’t show it. BTW, you’re expected to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I'm not sure how to utilize it, if it is of some help.